# RewriteEngine On repeating few times

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my .htaccess file but I can see that `RewriteEngine On` is repeating few a times. Can I remove some of `RewriteEngine On`?

Also I am interested if the rest of the code from WP Rocket is OK?

```
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "WP Rocket/2.6.7"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Don't compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/html .html_gzip
AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/feed/)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mounted-storage/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/mounted-storage/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END WP Rocket

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: RewriteEngine directive should be used once per htaccess file.

Comment: Correct, though I believe Apache simply ignores duplicate directives like that. I think what's happening here is that WP Rocket is adding things to the file, and can't give consideration to the other `RewriteEngine` directives as they, too, may be checked. For example, I think WP checks the contents between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`. The previous `RewriteEngine` directive seems to have been manually added (that's an assumption) and the one before that was added by WP Rocket within its scope. (Adding this as a comment as much of it is *speculation*, as it were.)

Answer (score 3):

As a general matter, it's totally normal for RewriteEngine On to be used multiple times in the same .htaccess files, because there is also a directive called RewriteEngine Off.

Since in your case the "off" directive is not used, you can simply remove duplicate instances of the "on" directive, but leaving them in won't hurt anything.